# general update pattern III, update values not showing up

Tags: d3.js

I am working on the modification of Mike Bostock's general update pattern III block and having a hard time understanding why, though the enter and exit values show up, the update values are not. I've read that assigning the specific value instead of using the data array value will help, as with a key, but this did not work. How do I modify this so entering values show up with their fill style, red color?  I have read SO posts and re-read "How Selections Work" but still can't make it work.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  text {
    font: bold 28px monospace;
  }

  .enter {
    fill: green;
  }

  .update {

    fill: red;
  }

  .exit {

    fill: blue;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="../d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script>
    function randomData() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    }


    var the_values = [];

    function randomEntry() {
      var numlist = [];

      var randomEntry;
      var maximum,minimum;
      maximum = 10; minimum = 1
      var random_in_range = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
      var length_of_array = random_in_range;
      console.log("length_of_array", length_of_array);

      for (i = 0; i < length_of_array; i++) {

        numlist.push([randomData(), randomData()]);
      }
      return numlist;
    }
    the_values = randomEntry();
    console.log("the_values", the_values);


    var width = 360,
      height = 400;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(32," + (height / 2) + ")");

    function update(data) {

      // DATA JOIN
      // Join new data with old elements, if any.
      var text = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(data, function(d) {
          return d;
        })
      .attr("transform", "translate(20," + (30) + ")");

       var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data, function(d) {
          return d;
         })
      .attr("transform", "translate(20," + (30) + ")");

      // UPDATE
      // Update old elements as needed.
      circles.attr("class", "update")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("opacity", 0.3)
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
         return d[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
         return d[1];
        })

      text.attr("class", "update")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
         return d[0];
       })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
          return d[1];
        })


      // ENTER
      // Create new elements as needed.
      circles.enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "enter")
        .attr("opacity", 0.3)
        .attr("r", 25)
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
          return d[0];
        })
         .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
          return d[1];
         })
         .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)

      .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);


      text.enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "enter")
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d[0];
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d[1];
         })
         .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
         .text(function(d) {
          return d[0];
         })
         .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);


      // EXIT
       // Remove old elements as needed.
      text.exit()
        .attr("class", "exit")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", 60)
         .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
         .remove();

      circles.exit()
        .attr("class", "exit")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)

      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
       .remove();
    }

    // The initial display.
    update(the_values);

    // Grab a random sample of letters from the alphabet, in alphabetical     order.
    setInterval(function() {
     update(randomEntry());
    }, 1500);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick glance at your code, it seems to be doing what you are looking for. Your enter circles are actually filled green, so you are actually seeing those. Updates are changed to red, but you don't see many of those because you are picking a few random numbers from 1-200. It's just unlikely that you will end up with any in the update selection, because that means that you selected the same number twice in a row.

To see some update circles, change:

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
```

To:

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
```

This throws the positions off, but you should soon see some red circles.

Comment: I think that the problem with the way the random numbers are collected is part of the issue because of the selection size as you point out.  Then I just need to figure out why the label positioning is not working.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in the update function you are always changing the whole array of input.

You are doing:

```
setInterval(function() {
 update(randomEntry());//this will change the full array set
}, 1500);
```

This should have been:

```
setInterval(function() {
  the_values.forEach(function(d){
    //change the data set for update
  }) 
 update(the_values);
}, 1500);
```

Please **note** above i have not created a new array but I am passing the same array with changes to the update function.

Working fiddle [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/paadX205xPjbmDuZh17D?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response, Cyril, but I believe the update is supposed to change the whole array as it is supposed to mimic the behavior of random data entering the system.  The changes you made do indeed make the data go from enter to update, but then the data never exit.

Comment: I illustrated how the update works! for exit you have to delete some points from the array. The main issue was that you were changing the full array, thats y it went into the enter/exit block and not in the update block.

Comment: Cyril, I am still learning about the general update patterns, so if I misunderstood your answer this is why.  I appreciate the help.